# Get Second Mysql Table Columns on Record set

Tags: mysql

please someone help me i need to get values of a second table in my columns below is my structure and the desired results:

**Table 1**

```
sysId   Fname       Sname           
1001    Martin      Mundia          
1002    Njoroge     William         
1003    Wainaina    Tim         
1004    Joel        Kinuthia
```

**Table 2**

```
id  Item    cost    sysId       
1   Shoes   100      1001       
2   Shirt   200      1001       
3   Trouser 150      1001       
4   Socks   300      1002       
5   Jacket  500      1002
```

**Desired Results**

```
1001    Martin  Mundia  Shoes(100)  Shirt(200)  Trouser(150)
1002    Njoroge William Socks(300)  Jacket(500)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.fname, t1.sname, group_concat(t2.item ,t2.cost)
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.sysid = T2.sysid
GROUP BY T1.sysid, t1.fname, t1.sname,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

> select a.sysId,a.fname,a.sname,group_concat(b.item,'(',b.cost,')')
>   from table1 a left outer join table2 b on a.sysId=b.sysId   order by a.sysId asc  group by
>   a.sysid,a.fname,a.sname;

Read more from [group_concat](http://manojbardhan2009.blogspot.in/2012/07/groupconcat-function-in-mysql.html) or [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select table1.sys_id,table1.fname,table1.sname,group_concat(table2.item,table2.cost)  
from table1 inner join table2  
on table1.sysId=table2.sysId  
group by tabl1.sysId,tabl1.fname,tabl1.sname;
```

thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for responses(Joe,JDeveloper,user2622406).Tested all and found the below being good since i need to also empty for those not having items......select a.Id,a.fname,a.sname,group_concat(b.item,'(',b.cost,')') from person a left outer join items b on a.Id=b.sysId  group by a.id,a.fname,a.sname order by a.Id asc

Comment: welcome and accept the most welcome answer for the future readings. Thanks.